# Can't access to attr_accessor in Concern Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to register the class method in concern and access to attr_accessor, but it doesn't work. This is my sample code. Please help me how can I do this. Thank you so much!

`app/controllers/concerns/foobar_concern.rb`

```
module FoobarConcern
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
    class << self
      attr_accessor :foo
    end
  end

   class_methods do
    def test_method(bar)
      self.foo = bar
    end
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/foobar_controller.rb`

```
class FoobarController < ApplicationController
   include FoobarConcern

   test_method 'Just test'

   def index
      self.foo => NoMethodError: undefined method "foo"
      foo => NameError: undefined local variable or method "foo"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just delegate required methods to the class like this

```
module FoobarConcern
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
    delegate :foo, :foo=, to: :class
    class << self
      attr_accessor :foo
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're defining a method at the **class** level (`FoobarController.foo`) but calling it on an **instance** of the class (`FoobarController.new.foo`).

One option is to call the `foo` method on the class instead:

```
def index
  self.class.foo
end
```

You can also define an accessor method for instances of the class like:

```
module FoobarConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class << self
      attr_accessor :foo
    end
  end

  class_methods do
    def test_method(bar)
      self.foo = bar
    end
  end

  # -- NEW --- 
  # This `foo` method is defined for instances of the class and calls the class method.
  def foo
    self.class.foo
  end


end
```